# Gracefully handeling exceptions when dealing with WhenAll

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm playing with a piece of code I wrote a while back. That piece of code deals with making a few requests in an async manner.

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var searchPromises = searchTerms
    .Select(GetSearchUrl)
    .Select(client.GetStringAsync);
var searchPages = await Task.WhenAll(searchPromises);
```

What happens is I create a new `HttpClient`. Using some search terch terms I compose search engine urls. Then I use those urls as inputs to get tasks representing the async requests for a page with the results. And last, I await those responses using `Task.WhenAll` to group them together.

The problem is if just one of those requests gets a 404, a 500 or anything like that my code throws an `AggregateException`.

Is there a way of specifying what should happen in the case of an error in one of those threads, so that I get a result from everything else?

I've looked at ContinueWith, but it doesn't seem to fit the bill, that is, it doesn't know how to deal with all the errors, just the aggregate one.

Comment: I can't see how you can do it without continuation. Look also to the child tasks attached to parent. You would be able to create a single parent task and attach to it n number of child tasks that you can observe exceptions independently.

Comment: How does `ContinueWith` *not* address the problem?

Answer (score 7):

> What happens is I create a new HttpClient. Using some search terch terms I compose search engine urls. Then I use those urls as inputs to get tasks representing the async requests for a page with the results. And last, I await those responses using Task.WhenAll to group them together.
>
> Is there a way of specifying what should happen in the case of an error in one of those threads, so that I get a result from everything else?

IMO, the easiest solution is to change how you think about the problem. Right now, you're thinking "perform a download on each url" and then "what for them all to complete and handle errors on a per-item basis". Just change your operation ("download") to include anything you want to do per-item. In other words, what you want to do is "perform a download on each url and handle errors" and then "wait for them all to complete":

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var searchPromises = searchTerms
  .Select(GetSearchUrl)
  .Select(url => DownloadAsync(client, url));
var searchPages = await Task.WhenAll(searchPromises);
var successfulSearchPages = searchPages.Where(x => x != null);

...

private static async Task<string> DownloadAsync(HttpClient client, string url)
{
  try
  {
    return await client.GetStringAsync(url);
  }
  catch (HttpRequestException ex)
  {
    // TODO: Perform appropriate error handling
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, that's kind of what I did in the end

Answer (score 3):

`Task.WhenAll` will return a task that is completed when all the tasks passed as argument are completed.

If any of the tasks passed as argument ends in a `Faulted` state (an exception was thrown), the returned task will also end in a `Faulted` state and its `Exception` property will contain the aggregation of all exceptions thrown by the tasks passed as argument.

Because the code generated by the compiler picks the first exceptin on the list, only the excpetion thrown by the first exception that throws (not the first exception thrwing) will be rethrown.

But the tasks passed as argument still exist and can still be queried for result.

This code snippet shows this working:

```
var tasks = new Task[] {
    ((Func<Task>)(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        await Task.Delay(10);
        await Task.Delay(10);
        throw new Exception("First");
    }))(),
    ((Func<Task>)(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        throw new Exception("Second");
    }))(),
    ((Func<Task>)(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
    }))()
};
var allTasks = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
try
{
    await allTasks;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Overall failed: {0}", ex.Message);
}


for(var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        await tasks[i];
        Console.WriteLine("Taks {0} succeeded!", i);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Taks {0} failed!", i);
    }
}

/*
Overall failed: First
Taks 0 failed!
Taks 1 failed!
Taks 2 succeeded!
*/
```

Comment: Why use `Task.Run(async () => { ..  })` here and not just something like `(Func<Task>(async () => { ..  })) ()` ?

Comment: @Noseratio, for no sane reason. That would be a comment I would make. But I started with sync examples and it ended up that way. I'll change it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own version of `Task.WhenAll` that returns just the results disregarding any exception using `Task.WhenAny`:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> WhenAllSwallowExceptions<TResult>(IEnumerable<Task<TResult>> tasks)
{
    var tasklist = tasks.ToList();
    var results = new List<TResult>();
    while (tasklist.Any())
    {
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasklist);
        try
        {
            results.Add(await completedTask);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // handle
        }

        tasklist.Remove(completedTask);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Usage:

```
var searchPages = await WhenAllSwallowExceptions(searchPromises);
```

This waits for tasks one at a time (with `Task.WhenAny`) and aggregates all the results (if there are any).

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of the result I'm also going for. Maybe a nice library for working with tasks would be nice to build :)

Comment: That's a perfect case for async iterators. Wonder if anyone working at Microsoft knows something about it

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do this, after many iterations. Tasks are starting to look like things that you need a library to abstract.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var exceptions = new ConcurrentBag<Exception>();

var searchPromises = searchTerms
    .Select(GetSearchUrl)
    .Select(client.GetStringAsync)
    .Select(t=>t.Catch(e=>exceptions.Add(e)));

var searchPages = (await Task.WhenAll(searchPromises))
    .Where(r => r != null);
```

And the implementation for `Catch`:

```
    public static Task<TResult> Catch<TResult>(this Task<TResult> self, Action<Exception> exceptionHandlerTask)
    {

        return self.ContinueWith(s =>
        {
            if (!s.IsFaulted)
            {
                return s.Result;
            }
            exceptionHandlerTask(s.Exception);
            return default(TResult);
        },
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously |
        TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
        TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
```

What happens now is that it gives you a way to append a failure state function to the `Task<T>` promise. This allows me to still have chainability. It is a shame that c# doesn't have robust support for functional pattern matching to make this easier.

Edit: added minimal code for error logging.

Edit: separated the code for logging errors to be more generic/reusable.

Edit: separated the code for saving the errors from the `Catch` function.

Comment: Not really, you need to understand what they do and why. For example your code doesn't really check for exceptions so they get lost. In order to create a LINQ statement, you ended up with code that doesn't handle exceptions properly.  Besides - `await` *is* an abstraction on top of Tasks, it's not Tasks - one created to make asynchronous code as easy to write as synchronous code.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, basically what I wanted to get was a way to separate the valid responses from the exceptions so that I could continue to use this in a linq pipline and handle the errors separately. Something like the way functional programming languages work with promises.

Comment: @linkerro then take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28988749/885318)

Comment: `exceptions.Add` within `ContinueWith` is a race condition.

Comment: @StephenCleary The code is async not multithreaded so I'm guessing it's not. However I do see this as needing a synchronized type when workind with parallel for or something.

Comment: @linkerro: You're using `ContinueWith` with some dangerous default option values. In the majority of cases, this will cause your line of code `exceptions.Add` to be run on thread pool threads. This is one reason to prefer `await` over `ContinueWith`; see [my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/01/a-tour-of-task-part-7-continuations.html) for other reasons as well.

Comment: @StephenCleary I see now what you meant. Nice blog post. My mind hurts now, but I see what you meant. Still, wouldn't this be solved by switching to a synched list or something?

Comment: @linkerro: Yes, you can synchronize your collection, either by using a lock or a concurrent collection.